# Finding function/class definitions in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, inspect

I want to find out where certain classes and functions are defined within PyTorch (and other libraries).

Unfortunately, the following doesn't work:

```
import inspect
import torch

inspect.getsource(torch.tensor)
```

It throws the following error:

```
TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method
```

What's more, within PyCharm, I usually do 'gd' (in vim mode) to find a function/class definition, but this doesn't work either for PyTorch.

Please help me understand what is the problem here, and more importantly, how I can find these definitions in general.

Comment: "It throws the following error" What throws this error? How are you running your code?

Comment: I'm running the code snippet I posted in the console.

Answer (score 1):

this is actually complicated. Pytorch/libtorch is a huge project, and it relies on a lot of builtin low-level functions which have been implemented in C/Cuda. Most low-level kernels (math operations for example) even have several implementations, in order to optimize differently for the CPU and the GPU etc.
So there is a lot in this library that is not python code, and `inspect` is going to have a hard time.

If you want to find the source files, you are probably going to need to dive in the [github repository](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch) yourself, and make good use of tools like `grep` and `find`.
However, the `torch.nn` module is almost entirely python, so I think `inspect` will work correctly on its features (like datasets, dataloaders, modules, optimizers etc)

And finally, if you need it, here is the file for `torch.tensor`, in which you will find python code mixed with calls to the C api : [torch tensor source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/09c0bb4fb9722c0d30a4985ded84d50da04e7f82/torch/_tensor.py#L50)

About the question in the comment below:

I cannot provide a full answer because this is reaching beyond my understanding of how exactly are python and C++ code interfaced in torch. But I'll do my best (If anyone has any correction or improvement to make to this, please do it).

There is a fundamental difference between C source code and python code : C/C++ are compiled and thus the features implemented in these languages are shipped as compiled assembly code. In other words, when your python code calls functions/objects from the underlying C code, it make calls to assembly functions that are not human-readable anymore. So the computer can make the calls, but the `inspect` feature that looks up for source code (for you to read) cannot work because this code does not exist anymore (at least not where `inspect` is looking). You would need other tools like a disassembler, a debugger etc, which are specialized in analyzing assembly instructions (you can also learn x86-64 assembly language programming if you are brave enough :D)

Comment: When doing 'import module from torch', and the module is implemented in C(++), why is it possible for the compiler to load the module('s code), but not for an IDE or something like inspect? What am I missing here?